# How to get collection detail from sub object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

My desired result is extracting this given output from collection named dashboard, I don't have id of dashboard collection object, the only thing i have is id of email object inside it:

I am giving you desired output and all necessary details:

Desired Output and Data stored in Dashboard collection

```
{
 email: { id: 5f8b4cfc0064d241048d8d2e, username: 'd@d.com' },
 _id: 5f8b4d670064d241048d8d2f,
 name: 'doud',
 age: 22,
 gender: 'male',
 height: 65,
 weight: 65,
 __v: 0
}
```

wrong written code:

```
router.get("/dashboard/:id", (req, res)=>{
    Dashboard.find({email:req.param.id}).populate("email").exec( (err, foundDashboard)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(foundDashboard);
            res.render("show", {dashboard: foundDashboard});
        }
    });
```

User schema

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});
```

Dashboard schema

```
var DashboardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // image: String,
    name: String,
    age:Number,
    gender: String,
    email: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    height: Number,
    weight: Number   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify this line and try.

`Dashboard.find({email:req.param.id}).populate("email").exec( (err, foundDashboard)=>{`

to

```
Dashboard.find({"email.id":req.param.id}).exec( (err, foundDashboard)=>{
```